# Cannot import XGBoostClassifier from xgboost4j-spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost

I have installed xgboost on my machine and now i am trying to run a simple scala project on spark trying to use the xgboost4j but i get the following error.

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
> >     ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/scala/spark/XGBoostClassifier

I have followed the instructions as shown here
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html
and here
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/xgboost4j_spark_tutorial.html

My project builds correctly with sbt.

When i look into my

`/xgboost/jvm-packages/xgboost4j/src/main/scala/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/scala`

the XGBoostClassifier class does not exist which is expected as shown in the scala api.

It exists into

`/xgboost/jvm-packages/xgboost4j-spark/src/main/scala/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/scala/spark`

The error appears when i try to import as shown

`import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassifier`

My build.sbt looks like this

```
name := "NewXGBoost"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
resolvers ++= Seq(
        "GitHub Repo" at "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CodingCat/xgboost/maven-repo/",
        Resolver.mavenLocal
)
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-yarn" % "2.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "ml.dmlc" % "xgboost4j-spark" % "0.82-SNAPSHOT"
libraryDependencies += "ml.dmlc" % "xgboost4j"  % "0.82-SNAPSHOT"
ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true)}
```

The desired result is for XGBoostClassifier to get correctly imported.

Comment: Do you want to run XGBoost of pure Scala (using DMatrix) or XGBoost Scala-Spark (Using Spark DataFrame)?

Comment: I am using spark dataframes

Comment: Is xgboost present in your maven repo? ~/.m2/repository/ml/dmlc?

Comment: No it is not. 
I have used mvn package and install inside jvm-packages of xgboost but it seems it did not add it.(mvn ended with success on everything)

Comment: But since i also add the git repo in the build, should it not find there?

Comment: Which exactly installation did you do from the xgboost doc and On which machine?

Comment: I used the installation for Ubuntu and afterwards followed the steps for JVM-Packages.
I can see the following on mvn install
``` [INFO] Installing /h/a/xgboost/jvm-packages/xgboost4j-spark/target/xgboost4j-spark-0.82-SNAPSHOT.jar to /root/.m2/repository/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j-spark/0.82-SNAPSHOT/xgboost4j-spark-0.82-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /h/a/xgboost/jvm-packages/xgboost4j-spark/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j-spark/0.82-SNAPSHOT/xgboost4j-spark-0.82-SNAPSHOT.pom ```

Comment: Not sure, but if it is installed locally maybe there is no need to use github resolver? If you keep only mavenLocal does it work? `resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal`

Comment: No, i had it like Resolver.mavenLocal in the start and it did not work.